# Pandas: create new column with group means conditional on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column containing group means conditional on the values of another column. This is best explained by example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [59000000, 65000000, 434000, 434000, 434000, 337000, 11300, 11300, 11300],
                   'B': [1, 1 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'group': ["IT", "IT", "IT", "MV", "MV", "MV", "IT", "MV", "MV"]})

df

          A  B group
0  59000000  1    IT
1  65000000  1    IT
2    434000  0    IT
3    434000  1    MV
4    434000  0    MV
5    337000  0    MV
6     11300  1    IT
7     11300  1    MV
8     11300  0    MV
```

I've managed to solve the problem but I am looking for something with less lines of code and possibly more efficient.

```
x = df.loc[df['B']==1].groupby('group', as_index=False)['A'].mean()
x.rename(columns = {'A':'a'}, inplace = True)
df = pd.merge(df, x, how='left', on='group')

          A  B group         a
0  59000000  1    IT  41337100
1  65000000  1    IT  41337100
2    434000  0    IT  41337100
3    434000  1    MV    222650
4    434000  0    MV    222650
5    337000  0    MV    222650
6     11300  1    IT  41337100
7     11300  1    MV    222650
8     11300  0    MV    222650
```

I've tried using the transform function but its not working for me

```
df.loc[: , 'a'] = df.groupby('group').transform(lambda x: x[x['B']==1]['A'].mean())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to filter only the values of col `A` you need, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['a'] = df['A'].where(df['B'].eq(1)).groupby(df['group']).transform('mean')
```

[out]

```
          A  B group           a
0  59000000  1    IT  41337100.0
1  65000000  1    IT  41337100.0
2    434000  0    IT  41337100.0
3    434000  1    MV    222650.0
4    434000  0    MV    222650.0
5    337000  0    MV    222650.0
6     11300  1    IT  41337100.0
7     11300  1    MV    222650.0
8     11300  0    MV    222650.0
```